# Pyspark Snowflake Connector Error With Df.Show

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The query is loading correctly I believe, but as soon as I use `df.show()` or `df.write.csv`, I get the following error. I can't seem to figure out what's causing this issue. Any insight/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**Error**

```
 py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o52.text.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/snowflake/client/jdbc/telemetry/TelemetryClient
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultJDBCWrapper$DataBaseOperations.getTelemetry(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:467)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.StageReader$.sendEgressUsage(StageReader.scala:124)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.StageReader$.readFromStage(StageReader.scala:57)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.package$.readRDD(package.scala:39)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.getSnowflakeRDD(SnowflakeRelation.scala:169)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.getRDD(SnowflakeRelation.scala:156)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.buildScan(SnowflakeRelation.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$3.apply(QueryExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$3.apply(QueryExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.stringOrError(QueryExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.text(DataFrameWriter.scala:597)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.telemetry.TelemetryClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

**Example Code**

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
import logging
from logging import getLogger
import queries
from snowflake_connector import ConnectToSnowflake

v_log = 'logs/spark.log'

sfOptions = ConnectToSnowflake(creds_path='creds.json').get_spark_sf_creds()

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.jars", "jars/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,jars/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.5.9-spark_2.4.jar,"
                          "jars/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.0.1.jar") \
    .config("spark.repl.local.jars",
            "jars/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,jars/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.5.9-spark_2.4.jar, "
            "jars/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.0.1.jar") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeConnectorUtils.enablePushdownSession(
    spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate())

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=v_log,
    level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = getLogger(__name__)

snowflake_source_name = 'net.snowflake.spark.snowflake'

df = spark.read.format(snowflake_source_name) \
    .options(**sfOptions) \
    .option("query", queries.getCustomerBaseQuery) \
    .load()

df.show()
```

Maybe this is a consequence of this warning:

```
2020-02-25 18:27:30 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is related with snowflake JDBC jar. Can you try to give full path of the jars? You may also try to use "--packages" option to load the required packages.

I am able to connect with the following:

```
pyspark --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.11.1,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.5.7-spark_2.4
```

Comment: You're right - I had to downgrade one of my jar files to an older version, and now it works